Problem regarding apply rotation change the outcome of the model
I am new to Blender. I followed a YouTube tutorial to create hair using circle and path curves. However, I encountered a problem my model changed after I hit "Apply Rotation" on the hair.
 The first picture is the intended design of the hair before the Ctrl + A
 After the rotation applied
Has anyone experienced something similar? I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

This is normal. Sweeping profiles along a curve is very dependent on the "external" orientation of objects and the "internal" orientation of the underlying mesh (or curve) in Edit Mode. If a mesh is pointing in a certain direction while the object is rotated, applying the rotation will set it to 0° but keep the mesh pointing in the same direction globally, and therefore the relative direction of the mesh towards the object it is contained within has changed. This breaks your model, since the profile depends on the orientation of the mesh within the object.

Therefore I would always recommend to only model something like this with the rotation applied beforehand. Or not apply it at all if it is not really relevant. What you could do now after applying is to go into Edit Mode and reverse the rotation of the mesh/curve itself. You said you were following a tutorial - how did they handle it there?

Hello Gordon, thank you for your responses. It seems that the tutorial I'm referring to is a quick one, so the tutor doesn't use the "apply rotation" feature. Perhaps for hair modeling, applying rotation isn't necessary. However, in my case, I'm modeling the king's face from a poker card, which has a symmetrical face and hair design. That's why I want to use the apply rotation feature to further apply mirror modifications.

The problem is not the applying itself, the problem is you have modeled to match the desired outcome while being rotated. You should have modeled it with a rotation of 0° degrees right from the start. Now, as I said, you can only try to reverse the rotation in Edit Mode so that it perhaps matches the desired outcome again. Or start again.

Hi Gordon, sorry that I don’t quite understand the reversing rotation in edit mode that you mentioned. Is it mean to adjust the mean tilt to 0?  Thanks for replying me.

No, it has nothing to do with the curve tilt. I have no idea how you have to reverse the rotation in your case. It depends on how the object was rotated before applying the rotation and how the profile followed the curve etc.

I understand what you mean now. My mistake was that the base hair model was rotated and not set to 0. Remodeling was one option, but I applied all the rotations, selected all the curve vertices, and adjusted the mean tilt in edit mode to match the desired outcome. Will this affect the model in the long run?
